# "Trying to get property 'taxonomy' of non-object" when using get_terms()

Tags: wordpress

I got the list of the terms of a specific taxonomy (GENRES), using this code:

```
     $categories = get_terms('genre', 'orderby=name&hide_empty=0');
     if($categories){
         echo '<select>';
         foreach ($categories as $cat){
         echo "<option value='{$cat->term_id}'>{$cat->name}</option>";
     }
     echo '</select>';
 }
```

The code works, but I want to get also the title of the taxonomy (GENRES), so for this I used `print_r($categories);` and I got this output:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => WP_Term Object ( 

        [term_id] => 33 
        [name] => Action 
        [slug] => action 
        [term_group] => 0 
        [term_taxonomy_id] => 33 
        [taxonomy] => genre 
        [description] => 
        [parent] => 0 
        [count] => 1 
        [filter] => raw 
    ) 
    [1] => WP_Term Object ( 
        [term_id] => 34 
        [name] => Comedy 
        [slug] => comedy 
        [term_group] => 0 
        [term_taxonomy_id] => 34 
        [taxonomy] => genre 
        [description] => 
        [parent] => 0 
        [count] => 2 
        [filter] => raw 
    ) 
)
```

Now for getting the title I used `print_r($categories->taxonomy);`, but I got "Trying to get property 'taxonomy' of non-object". Why does this error occur, and how to get the title of taxonomy using my implementation?

Comment: Removed tags from title; grammar; layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function `get_terms()` returns an array of objects, not single object.

So, just use `$categories[0]->taxonomy` and you will get an output "genre".